# How restore mysql database without frm files

Tags: mysql

Hackers were crypt all my frm files of my mysql databases, but *.ibd files and ibdata1 file are safe.
Can i restore my frm files from this files ?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is much easier to just restore the frm files from backup and then run a consistency check.

Comment: yes but they encrypted all backup files too in other server ... I'm screwed?

Comment: if they really got all your backups too, then I think it might be game over.

Comment: If you take the offline backup you might fall back a bit in time, but it might still work.